Reading key values from JSON
I have the following JSON, and I have tried various formats of reading a specific key without success.
This is a web push notification coming from TalkJS, below.
As well as what it looks like in the console.
I am looking for the TEXT key value, which in this case is hello
I have tried payload.text and payload.message.text but they both come out undefined.

"{"message":{"id":"msg_303fpzqsELNIYT6udk6A52","type":"UserMessage","origin":"web","location":null,"text":"hello","custom":{},"content":[{"children":["hello"],"type":"text"}],"attachment":null,"createdAt":1735132581656,"conversationId":"1734948015815","editedAt":null,"referencedMessageId":null,"senderId":"user","readBy":[]},"timestamp":1735132581656,"body":"hello","sender":{"id":"user","name":"User Tap","custom":{},"email":["user@house.com"],"role":"thadmin","locale":"en-EN","photoUrl":"https://talkjs.com/images/avatar-4.jpg","createdAt":1730821509211,"welcomeMessage":"Hi!","phone":null,"availabilityText":null,"pushTokens":{}},"conversation":{"id":"1734948015815","custom":{"status":"open","type":"personal"},"subject":"test55","photoUrl":null,"participants":[],"createdAt":1734948017190,"topicId":null,"welcomeMessages":null}}"


Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

You have another JSON string in the middle which is not yet parsed. Try JSON.parse(payload.data.talkjs).message.text

@CherryDT - perfect, thank you. Could you explain why the parse needs to be done on the talkjs object but the message.text is not part of the parse?  Thank you

I don't understand the question. You can see payload.data.talkjs is a JSON-encoded object as a string so we need to parse that. Then on the result (now an object) we access the message.text property.

Can you try this one:
const talkjsData = payload.data.talkjs;
const parsedTalkjsData = JSON.parse(talkjsData);
const textValue = parsedTalkjsData.text;
console.log(textValue); 


Getting: talkjs.text:undefined for that textValue

You should JSON.parse() the talkjs value.


const response = {
data: {
talkjs: "{\"message\":{\"id\":\"msg_303fpzqsELNIYT6udk6A52\",\"text\":\"hello\"}}"
}
};

const talkjs = JSON.parse(response.data.talkjs);

console.log(talkjs.message.text)




Getting error ReferenceError: response is not defined on this

@kneidels How do you call API? If you use axios you can get this response in then block. Share full code so we can help you better
